# Read CSV and render it to display as Datatables not working

Tags: python, pandas, flask, bootstrap-4, datatables

In the below file app.py, after reading the csv content and converting it into string, the rendered content comes together as a single column in datatable output.
How could i split the csv content as separate columns, so that it gets properly rendered in datatable.
I even tried converting it into to_dict or to_html format but its not working.
The best possible output of rendering my csv content in datatable format is this till now by converting it into string.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask,url_for, render_template, redirect, request
import csv
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def root():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('home.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        results = []

        file = request.form['upload-file']
        data = pd.read_csv(file)
        reader = csv.DictReader(data)
        
        for row in reader:
             results.append(dict(row))

        fieldnames = [key for key in results[0].keys()]

        return render_template('home.html', results=results, fieldnames=fieldnames, len=len)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <!--link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='images/favicon.ico')}}"-->


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Datatable -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.5/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.21/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.21/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post">
          <input type="file" class="form-control" rows="5" name="upload-file">
          <button class="btn btn-success mt-2">Render CSV</button>
        </form>
        <div class="mt-4">
          {% if request.method == 'POST'%}
            <table id="proxies" class="display table table-striped table-bordered responsive hover nowrap" style="width: 100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  {% for header in results[0].keys() %}
                    <th>{{header}}</th>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for row in results %}
                  <tr>
                    {% for index in range(0, len(fieldnames)) %}
                      <td>{{row[fieldnames[index]]}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

  <!--dataTables-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.5/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/dataRender/datetime.js"></script>



  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#proxies').DataTable();
  </script>

</html>
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to load the data / HTML table as an AJAX request from your HTML using a second route in `Flask`.  My HTML doesn't have any CSS so it's formatting is default.  Also I'm using port 3000 as I'm using port 5000 for another app.

```
import pandas as pd, json
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/handle_data', methods=["POST"])
def handle_data():
    df = pd.read_csv("players.csv")
    return Response(df.to_html())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=3000)
```

#### home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="main">
        <section id="data-section">
            <h2>Data</h2>
            <div id="data"/>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
<script>
    function apicall(url) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST", url:url, 
            success: (data) => { $("#data").html(data); }
        });
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        apicall("/handle_data");
    }
</script>
</html>
```

#### output

[image]

#### preserve table formatting

This will mean table in DOM has same *id* *class* and *style* as your `home.html`

```
            success: (data) => { 
                $("#data").html(data);
                t = $("#data>table");
                t.attr("id", "proxies");
                t.addClass("display table table-striped table-bordered responsive hover nowrap");
                t.css({"width":"100%"});
             }
```

Comment: Thanks Rob but i want to use Datatables feature. I need to use it further to export into different formats etc which can be done using Datatables.

Comment: so you want `<table id="proxies" class="display table table-striped table-bordered responsive hover nowrap" style="width: 100%">` this in the table definition?  nothing else?

Comment: I've supplemented answer.  If you want specific attributes in HTML then it's simple JQuery on the DOM

Comment: No, I guess I wrote the wrong logic in for loop statement to make each for loop call. Can you tell me if it is correct or not?